# How to setup elasticsearch snapshot repository for multinode?

Tags: elasticsearch

I setup a snapshot repository for one node ES cluster running inside a container.
version 7.7.1

```
path.repo=[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshot]

PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
"type": "fs",
"settings": {
"location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/snapshot"
}
```

}

It works well.

However in a multinode cluster it fails with `RepositoryVerificationException`.

How should I change the above code to be able to use it?

I come across these sources but both of them unclear about what to do exactly:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-register-repository.html

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/snapshot-and-path-repo-on-one-cluster-node/155717

Comment: Is the directory `/etc/elasticsearch/snapshot` mounted from a persistent volume or it exists only in inside your countainer? All your nodes need to have access to this directory.

Comment: @leandrojmp the whole '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/' is mounted as PV. However it is mounted the by kubernetes so I don't know the persistent directory name in advance.
The current directory name is 
/mount/nfs/my-elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0-pvc-f456009b-b3d7-a121-6772-53ga87f47999.
^^ inside this I can see the 'snapshot' directory